# Regarding Samsung Monitor 733NW

Tags: windows

My monitor is turning off and on frequently for a few days.While doing any work suddenly display is turning off but background work is going fine and after some time it is turning on and this repeats.

Comment: Have you tried another monitor - then you know it's not a software problem. Otherwise you need to bring the monitor to your hardware dealer - looks pretty much broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with LCD monitors. Its caused by one or more of the capacitors starting to fail, and intermittently blank the display. The solution is to replace them. They are inexpensive and [easy to detect by their buldging top](http://www.markdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/bulging_capacitors.jpg). Search for generic solutions to LCD monitor blinkins/replace capacitors, like [this one:](http://www.markdigital.com/2011/02/14/bad-capacitors-lcd-monitor-repaired/) with links to other sites.